# Mongodb: perform case insensitive sorting using reactivemongo

Tags: mongodb, reactivemongo

To facilitate `case insensitive sorting`, **Mongodb 3.4** provides [Case Insensitive Indexes](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/core/index-case-insensitive/). We can `create a index` and then `use collation in the query` to use that index as:

```
db.fruit.find( { type: "apple" } ).collation( { locale: 'en', strength: 2 } )
```

I am using [ReactiveMongo 0.12.2](http://reactivemongo.org/releases/0.12/documentation/release-details.html) which supports Mongodb 3.4.And I need to `perform above collation query with reactivemongo`. I could not find any documentation regarding this.

How can I perform such query this ?

Comment: MongoDB 3.4 is not yet supported

Comment: @cchantep is there any update on this feature ?